# Enabling rtmp_swfurl option in FFmpeg

Tags: unix, ffmpeg

In Unix, in order to process RTMP live stream URLs some live streams needs `swfurl`, `pageurl` extra. We are able to pass this parameters to the `RtmpDump` and pipe it to the FFmpeg.

However some FFmpeg has `rtmp_swfurl` its own. How can we enable this options in FFmpeg, not all of them have. Although I have latest version I do not have them.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by first removing libav-tools and installing ffmpeg manually after download last version from its web site. When I try to install ffmpeg without removing libav-tools it did not work, hence you should remove then install ffmpeg and install libav-tools again

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove libav-tools
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```